# Why is onupgradeneeded never called in this code?

Tags: indexeddb

I'm trying to insert data in my indexed db, but the function onupgradeneed never is called, just onsuccess. The version of the database is always the same (it is a global variable).
I have understood that in order to get into onupgradeneed the version have to be always the same. In my case, it is in this way.
So, I have no data... What can I do?
Thanks!

```
var db;
var dbname = "mi";
var dbversion = 1;

function abrirDB()
{
    if (plataforma == plataformaW8) {
        if (db == null) {
            var request = window.indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
            request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                db = evt.target.result;
                if (db.objectStoreNames.length == 0)
                    crearDB();
            };
            }
        }
}
function crearDB() {


   //Declaración datos BBDD

        var paisesData = [{ id_pais: 1, pais: "Arabia Saudí", continente: "Asia", capital: "Riad", paisurl: "arabiasaudi", continenteurl: "asia" },
      { id_pais: 2, pais: "Emiratos Árabes Unidos", continente: "Asia", capital: "Abu Dhabi", paisurl: "emiratosarabes", continenteurl: "asia" }];


    //////////

    //Abrir BBDD
    var request =window.indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);

    request.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("Error al abrir la bbdd" + evt.target.errorCode);
    };


    request.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
       db = evt.target.result;

        var storePaises = db.createObjectStore(storePaisesNombre, { keyPath: "id_pais", autoincrement: false, unique: true });
      .......
    request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        //db = request.result;
        db = evt.target.result;
    };

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your dbversion variable to 2. This way the db will open in a newer version and the onupgradeneeded callback will get called

Answer (score 2):

you can change version 1 for two, it worked for me like this:

```
let openRequest = window.indexedDB.open ("MyTestDatabase", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using a global db variable, even if some examples show it. It just leads to problems for newer programmers. Try reviewing my answer at [How to get objectstore from indexedDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898375/how-to-get-objectstore-from-indexeddb/16379163#16379163) for help.

Comment: I have already solved it. It was a problem in another file that was calling a function before my request had finished.